# Any way to stop a Index Seek with a range predicate?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

SQL Server 2008 R2

I am joining two huge tables to each other .. the query looks something like:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Parent p
INNER JOIN Child c ON c.ID = p.ID
<further joins>
WHERE p.ID IN (9558207665, 9558213992, 9558245267, 9558291779, 9558403049)
```

Both tables have clustered indexes on ID.

The query plan is creating a Clustered Index Seek (on the child table, interestingly enough), but is using a range predicate from 9558207665 through 9558403049.  This causes a read of 400,000+ records, since the child table has multiple records for a given ID. It's causing an issue, especially when I specified the actual 5 IDs I wanted.

The only way I've been able to make it not do that is to create a table variable with the 5 IDs and use it as the initial FROM table, linking to it.

I understand that, for some reason, statistics indicate that the range would be faster than the individual lookups, but since that ends up being the wrong choice, is there some other way of forcing the seek to do individual lookups?

Comment: Have you updated statistics on the tables?

Comment: No.  It's simply too large.  But, I'm more interested in forcing the plan to BEND TO MY WILL!

Besides, we've all had the fun of a perfectly good query going all hinky when statistics change or something else causes a recompile.  I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: You can use HINTS in your query. Read about it on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx).

Comment: I haven't found an acceptable hint. Thanks, though. If you have ideas on a specific hint, I'm happy to take a look at it.

Comment: What you're going to avoid is allowing SQL Server to properly adapt to changing data. If your table statistics aren't being kept up to date then that's the problem that you should be addressing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with large tables, using small correlated range joins, it's sometimes necessary to add seemingly redundant filters.

```
SELECT ...
FROM Parent p
INNER JOIN Child c ON c.ID = p.ID
<further joins>
WHERE p.ID IN (9558207665, 9558213992, 9558245267, 9558291779, 9558403049)
AND c.ID IN (9558207665, 9558213992, 9558245267, 9558291779, 9558403049)
```

Comment: I did discover that, but I'd really like to put it into a view.  I don't have access to the internal tables to do that.  Good thought, though... If nothing better comes up, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: What happens if you expose the child ID column from the view instead of the parent ID then?

Comment: I can play with that, but not sure it will help. I could expose both and then use your trick.